# How do I generate a sandboxed ExtJS 7.3 app?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sandbox, extjs7

Ok, I keep reading about this in almost a-decade-old threads but I can't seem to find any details:

- I have an *(let's call it)* app with a lot of components running Extjs 6.5, the complete version of the library is included (ext-all.js) and then my minified class definition files
- now I need to include to the very same page only one component which should be running Extjs 7.3 and it should package only the necessary classes for its functioning, so I will most likely have to use Sencha CMD (any better approaches?) to generate it

That means I need to include both ext-all.js (6.5) for all the old components and my-custom-subset-ext.js (7.3) for the new component. I have no problem generating the 7.3 subset but how do I get the **sandboxed** version? I can't find anything relevant about sandboxing in the docs. There is just a few notes about different extjs file versions. Several questions on SO/old Sencha forum mention it used to be possible.

Is it still possible? If so, how? How do I set up Sencha CMD to give me custom-namespaced files?
All I can see is this in the ext-all-debug.js

```
Ext.sandboxName = 'Ext6';
Ext.isSandboxed = true;
Ext.buildSettings = { baseCSSPrefix: "x6-", scopeResetCSS: true };
```

I am using 7.3.0.55 but it still uses Ext6 as the sandbox name which makes me think that they dropped the ball on this one. Neither `sandboxName` nor `isSandboxed` is documented. But maybe I am just really blind and I missed something very obvious...

Any help appreciated. Thanks!